# SPFx Field Customizer - serve.json does not support utf-8 characters in field name

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint, utf-8, spfx

I am trying to apply Field Customizer on SharePoint site(online).
First, I generate the project by running the Yeoman SharePoint Generator. All of this goes fine, until I try to modify the `serve.json` file.

```
"helloWorld": {
      "pageUrl": "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/Lists/List1/AllItems.aspx",
      "fieldCustomizers": {
        "FieldName": {
          "id": "1b20fbc6-0a72-4cdd-c352-cac47a9f917e",
          "properties": {
            "sampleText": "Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here, I need to update the `FieldName`. Because of the fact that `FieldName` needs to be the display name of the field and not internal name (idk why - the internal name do not even trigger the script when `gulp serve` is run), I need to use utf-8 characters here(site is meant to be used in language where chars like `š,č,ř,ž` and so on are common).

But when I try to rename `FieldName` to for example `Kočka`, I get message `Property Kočka is not allowed.` and afterwards the `gulp serve` will fail.
I tried to use unicode, so `\u004b\u006f\u010d\u006b\u0061` but again, the same message is displayed.

Only thing I found out is that when I set the `FieldName` to display name of the field which does not contain these special characters - then the Field Customizer will apply to this field, aftewards I can go to URL and replace the `FieldName` there to actually typing in `Kočka` and customizer will apply to this field.

However, this is not good workaround and I think this will work only in debug, not in actual deployment in the future.

Does anybody know how it could be done that the json would accept utf-8 characters?

Thanks in advance